# Node.js app with users connected to different databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a node.js (and express) product administration app which connects to a mongodb database containing the produt data, and uses Stormpath for user administration.

This was all fine, but now I need the app to be able to connect to two different databases - one for UK products and one for US products. The users need to be able to switch between the UK and US databases whenever they like.

I have been able to make this work for the whole app just by adding a button which disconnects from one db and connects (using MongoClient) to the other, but what I need is to either have two connections at all times, and pick which one to use based on which country the user has selected, or to have a db connection per user.

Which is the correct way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can spawn 2 active mongodb connections, it is possible.
According to - [npm module of mongodb documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

```
var 
  mongo = require('mongodb'),
  MongoClient1 = mongo.MongoClient,
  MongoClient2 = mongo.MongoClient;


MongoClient1.connect('mongodb://somehost1:27017/db1', function(err, db) {
   //do things
});

MongoClient2.connect('mongodb://somehost2:27017/db2', function(err, db) {
   //do things
});
```

than you can dependency inject this database clients into the request.
The reconnection to database can take time, and users can experience a bad performance. I think it is better to keep 2 active connections alwayes.